# Google Voice Search no longer automatically takes action

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-now, google, google-voice-actions

I was recently using my phone and noticed something odd. Previously, when I used Google Voice Search, and I said something like "Set a timer for 10 minutes", my phone would recognize that I wanted to set a timer, and if I took no action, would automatically start the timer after a short duration. Now, when I take this action, the phone recognizes the voice command, but only has a button labelled "Start Timer".

I'm not sure what in particular has changed, but I haven't found any similar problems via Googling. The only thing I can think of is that I recently upgraded to Cyanogenmod M11.

How can I regain the previous behaviour of Google Voice Search?

Answer (score 0):

Same here on Xperia Z2..

If you uninstall updates to the Google search app functionality is restored so it is definitely a Google update